# Rails join table in Trestle/Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm rewriting an old PHP application in Rails 5.1 and migrating the database, too.

I have the two tables with data:

```
table: jobs
id   library
-------------
20   foo-20
200  bar-200

table: manuscripts
id    job_id  shelfmark
-----------------------
743   200     MS0403
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to display:

```
library    shelfmark 
---------------------
bar-200        MS0403
```

But I'm getting foo-20 instead of bar-200 for library:

```
library    shelfmark
--------------------
foo-20     MS0403
```

The foreign key job_id seems to be wrongly referenced.

and the models:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :manuscripts
end

class Manuscript < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :job
  belongs_to :job
end
```

In TrestleAdmin app/admin/manuscripts_admin.rb

```
Trestle.resource(:manuscripts) do

  table do
    column :library, ->(ob) { ob.job.library }
    column :shelfmark
  end
end
```

How can I correct that?

Comment: You will have to manually update the corrupted data, either by using a sql inline console, a GUI SQL (like pgAdmin for PostgreSQL) or directly use Rails' console in the relevant mode (production/development).

Comment: the database data isn't corrupt (the php application references it correctly). I suppose it's an issue with my Rails models.

Comment: *The foreign key job_id seems to be wrongly referenced* this suggested (to me) that the data was corrupted. Can you make sure that the associated library is wrong in your IRB (rails console)? -- Also, in `Job`, a `has_one` expect a singularized relation name, so it should be `has_one :manuscript`. -- Oh, and there is two definitions for the same relation `Manuscript` <> `Job`, you should only have the `belongs_to :job` and not the `has_one :job`

Comment: Remove the `has_one :job` from `Manuscript`.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Could you provide your comments as an answer? So I can accept it as the solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You should be using a `belongs_to` relationship on the `Manuscript` table and remove the `has_one` relationship:

```
class Manuscript < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
end
```

**Explanation**

The `belongs_to` association tells Rails to look for the foreign key in the current model's table.  In your case `belongs_to :job` tells Rails to look for a `job_id` in the `manuscripts` table.  This is the table schema you are using, and is therefore the correct association.

Conversely, the `has_one` association tells Rails to look for the foreign key in the associated (other) table.  In this case `has_one :job` tells Rails to look for a `manuscript_id` in the `jobs` table.  Based on the schema you provided, this in incorrect.

You can read more about this in the [Ruby on Rails Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one).

**Caveat**

Based on the error you are experiencing, you may also have corrupt data in your database.  You will need to fix any corrupt data to make this work. But, removing the `has_one` may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the detailed answer! In my case I don't have a manuscript_id in the jobs table. But it works nevertheless.

Comment: Exactly, that is why `has_one :job` is not appropriate.